# A function that is in the $L^p$ space for some $p \ge 1$ and uniformly continuous, has a limit of $0$ as $||x|| \rightarrow \infty.$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let, $p \in [1,\infty)$. Suppose, $g \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^{n},m)$ where $m$ is the n'th dimensional Leb. measure, and $g$ is uniformly cont. Then,
$$\lim_{||x|| \rightarrow \infty}g(x) = 0.$$

Suppose, $\lim_{||x|| \rightarrow \infty}g(x) \ne 0$. Then, $\exists \epsilon >0:$
$$\forall M \in \mathbb{R}, \exists \alpha, ~ ||\alpha|| > M ~ \land  ~  |g(\alpha)| > \epsilon.$$
Then we can construct an increasing sequence (w.r.t. the norm) $\{\alpha_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ such that, $|g(\alpha_n)| > \epsilon$ and $||x_n|| < ||x_{n+1}|| + 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

By uniform continuity we have that, $\exists \delta,\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$:
$$||x-y|| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| <  \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
Let, $S = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} B(\alpha_n,\min\{\delta,1\}).$ The ball of radius $\min\{\delta,1\}$ centered at $\alpha_n$.
We have that,

$$\int_{S}(\frac{\epsilon}{2})^{p} ~ dm \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|g|^p ~ dm.$$

Observe that, $\mu(S) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \min\{1,\alpha\} = \infty.$ Thus,
$$\infty \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|g|^p ~ dm. $$

Which is a contradiction to $g \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n},m)$.

EDIT:
Thank you, @MathematicsStudent1122 for the tip.

Comment: If $\limsup_{||x|| \to +\infty} |g(x)|=\alpha>0$, then by uniform continuity you can, for some $\delta>0$, find infinitely many disjoint balls of radius $\delta$ on which $g$ is $\geq \alpha/2$. This forces the integral to be $+\infty$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 

I see now, thanks! I forgot uniform continuity, to make this work.